# Trying to get property 'values' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

Im trying to get this code working. But it won't work. But when I replace the **$item->item_id** with at static number the code works fine, just not dynamic output.

```
foreach ($collection as $item) {

            print 'title: '. $item->title . '<br>';
            print 'link: '. $item->link . '<br>';
            print 'item_id: '. $item->item_id  . '<br>';

            $test = PodioItem::get_basic($item->item_id); // replace it with a static number
            print $test->fields['brugernavn']->values . '<br>';
        }
```

The issue is that I get this error "Trying to get property 'values' of non-object"

[image]

Comment: print_r($collection) and see what are you getting there.

Comment: When you get this type of error check what is inside your variable by using a `var_dump`, here `var_dump($collection);`.

Comment: Not all of your `$test` will have a filed `brugernavn`. Try to check for existence of that before print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

You are iterating over a collection of items. For each of those items you will do some stuff. If for *one* item of the collection this stuff won't work (throws an error), the error message won't tell you which.

If you now choose a single item from the collection you know that the stuff you do is working on (here: has an `item_id`), it is no wonder, that it works.

How to circumvent this?

First, you should check your actual data for any flaws. Do this by examining the values of that data right before the error occurs (`print_r`, `var_dump` or use xdebug). You will find that not every item will have a `field['brugernavn']`

To avoid this error: Before doing the stuff, make sure, the stuff will work. In your case you should check, if `field['brugernavn']` exists and has a reasonable value like so:

```
if (isset($test->fields['brugernavn']) && isset($test->fields['brugernavn']->values)) {
    print $test->fields['brugernavn']->values . '<br>';
}
```